# How to run sudo commands in shell/linux using python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell, sudo

How to run `sudo bash` using python script

```
import subprocess
import os

sudoPassword2 = 'abcd1234'
command2 = 'sudo bash'
p2 = os.system('echo %s|sudo -S %s' % (sudoPassword2, command2))
```

I'm getting this error:

```
bash: line 1: abcd1234: command not found
```

when i tried to this also its giving error

```
import shlex
import subprocess


command1 = shlex.split('cd /home/backups')
subprocess.call(command1)
```

error  cd no file or dir

tried also this :

```
import shlex
import subprocess



subprocess.call(["cd","/home","/backups"])
```

Comment: Appears that this happens because bash expects input and since there's nothing else it uses the args from echo ...

Comment: Run your script itself under sudo. Do not include your sudo password in a script, as it defeats the purpose of having a password in the first place. If you must, reconfigure sudo to allow your specific command without a password, though do not do it without being aware of the security implications.

Comment: `cd` is not a program. Use `os.chdir` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use os module

```
import os

os.system("sudo and the code you want to run")
```

in example:

```
import os

os.system("sudo apt-get vlc")
```

Comment: There still will be credentials in the script. This is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because your command posts the password to the cli first without being asked for it. So bash will interpret it as a command which, obviously, can not be executed.

Better do `os.system('sudo command')` and call the script as root or via sudo. This will make sure you have the necessary privileges within the script immediately at run time.

Another reason why you definitely want to refrain from doing what you do is the necessity of having the sudo password for your machine written into the script in plain text. Never do that. It's evil.

If there is no way around you can make sudo execute a command without asking for a password by adding `NOPASSWD` directives to the `/etc/sudoers` by using the editor `visudo` (never use anything different) like so:

```
user host = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
user host = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
```

But if you do make sure you know that this opens the execution of this command to anyone on the system without needing elevated rights. This can be a huge security risk.

Comment: Edit of question did not clarify. What are you trying to execute in the first place? Only `cd` into a directory? Why shlex? Did you try my solution just using `os.system('...')`?

Comment: Maybe this is the point to tell us what your program is supposed to do. I suspect there could be an easier solution for the task than the one you are going for at the moment.